# How do you find and delete the highest integer in a list of unknown integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to delete the biggest integer in a list of unknown integers. Basically I have this:

```
list=[x,y,z...]
```

I know how to find the biggest integer:

```
max=max(list)
```

But what I want to do is then be able to delete that number from the list. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? The easiest solution is probably to sort the list and remove the corresponding extremity.

Comment: `list.pop(list.index(max(list)))`?? If one max value

Comment: @SIslam: `l.remove(max(l))` also works...

Comment: `x = sort(list)`; `new_x=x[:-1]`

Comment: @timgeb..after sorting the max number will be at the end of list, so that's why he did `new_x=x[:-1]` but that will remove only one max in case there were duplicate max

Comment: @IronFist I think I got his idea :) it's still `sorted`, though.

Comment: @IronFist yes i forget about this case. And function is `sorted`, yes

Comment: I think list comprehension is the best approach here, nop?

Comment: @IronFist in Python2 I would have liked `filter` better, but in Python3 most of the time they become harder to read than the comprehension because of the additional call to `list`. I wish `map` and `filter` had a default argument like `makelist=False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> numbers = [3, 5, 77, 8]
>>> max_number = max(numbers)
>>> numbers[:] = [number for number in numbers if number != max_number]
>>> numbers
[3, 5, 8]
```

Deleting implies that you want to keep the original object. `numbers[:] =` does this:

```
numbers = [3, 5, 77, 8]
print(id(numbers))
max_number = max(numbers)
numbers[:] = [number for number in numbers if number != max_number]
print(id(numbers))
```

prints:

```
4421673608
4421673608
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, don't use `list` as a variable name, you are shadowing the name of the builtin `list`. The following code will create a new list from a list `lst` with every element that is the maximum (remember that there could be multiple such elements) removed and reassign it to the name `lst`.

```
max_el = max(lst)
lst = [x for x in lst if x != max_el]
```

If you want to remove the maximum element only once (i.e. its first occurence), and do it in-place, the answer from @KevinGuan in the comments works fine:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,1,3]
>>> lst.remove(max(lst))
>>> lst
[1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks that's just what I needed

Comment: Yes another option may be-`filter(lambda x: x!=max(lst),lst)`

Comment: @SIslam...better assign `max(lst)` to a variable rather than call it on each value of `lst`

Comment: @SIslam Yep, that works too. Just remember that the asker is using Python3, where `filter` returns a filter object which you must make a list of manually, i.e. `list(filter(...))`.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> m = max(l)
>>> [i for i in l if i != m]
[1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: I added your approach from the comments to my answer, I hope you don't mind. If you want to add it to yours, I'll remove it.

Comment: @timgeb: Oh, my comment on question. No problem, it's good :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> mx = max(lst)
>>> lst = list(filter(lambda x: x!=mx, lst)) #Python3, filter returns generator, so convert it to list
```